# How to pass by value using a pointer?

Tags: c++

If I have a function defined as follows,

```
void foo(MyObject o){

}
```

and I have a pointer to a `MyObject`, say `MyObject *o`, How can I call the function passing the object as an argument using the pointer to the object?

How can I go about doing that without changing the body/signature of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply with

```
foo(*o);
```

That will create a copy by the way.

Comment: Yea it works, thanks,  I was trying to do it like this `foo(&o);` and the compiler kept complaining that I was giving a pointer to a pointer. and I didnt know the proper syntax.